# nginx does not serve the Django admin statics file

Tags: python-3.x, nginx, django-3.0

I have a django project in production on DigitalOcean.
Static files are well served for the application itself, but not for the admin part

settings.py

```py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

/etc/nginx/sites-available/my-project

```
server {
        ...

        location /static/ {
                root /home/username/my-project;
        }

        location /media {
                autoindex on;
                alias /home/username/my-project/media/;
        }

        location / {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
        }
}
```

when I check in console if the static admin files have been collected

- cd my-project/staticfiles
- ls

```
admin  css  images  js
```

cd admin

```
css  fonts  img  js
```

EDIT

Let's play with URLs

Here I try to display my css on the public part of my application.

```
my-domain.name/static/css/stylesheet.css
```

The file is well served

Now I’m trying to display the Django admin app css

```
my-domain.name/static/admin/css/dashboard.css
```

The page returns a 404 code

I do not know if this is related to my problem but i modified the url of the admin.

```py
path('ez4y5ebGgTkfanLYHdjbX33pQMyX/', admin.site.urls), # the admin url is a long sequence of numeric alpha characters
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you run **collectstatic** ?

`django.contrib.staticfiles` provides a convenience management command for gathering static files in a single directory so you can serve them easily on production.

Change your **STATIC_ROOT**

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

and run collect static

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

This will copy all files from your static folders into the **STATIC_ROOT** directory.

Comment: Yes the command collectstatic has been executed.
and the static admin files have been collected in the staticfiles folder

Comment: 6 * Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: updated answer try this it will work now !
let me know if this doesnt

Comment: I see what you mean.
However, I did it a little differently.
I want to differentiate the static folder from the staticfiles folder,
so I did not modify settings.py but I simply copy / paste the static Django admin files to put them in my static folder.
And it worked perfectly.

Thanks a lot for your help